# Django REST generic ListCreateView GET request is working but POST request is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created a generic ListCreateAPI view. I am able to execute a GET request to the view but not a POST request.

Here is my model:

```
class InvoiceEntry(models.Model):

    SERVICE_OR_EXPENSE_CHOICE = [('SER', 'Service'),('EXP', 'Expense')]
    TYPE_CHOICE = [('BPA', 'BPA'),('CAE', 'CAE'),('MEC', 'MEC'),('TRA', 'Travel')]

    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rate = models.FloatField()
    units = models.FloatField()
    discount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    service_or_expense = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SERVICE_OR_EXPENSE_CHOICE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[' + str(self.invoice_number) + '][' + self.description + '][' + self.service_or_expense  + '][' + self.type + ']'
```

Here is my view:

```
class InvoiceEntryListCreate(ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = InvoiceEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceEntrySerializer
```

And here is my serializer:

```
class InvoiceEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = InvoiceEntry
    fields = ['invoice_number', 'description', 'rate', 'units', 'discount', 'amount', 'service_or_expense', 'type']
```

I get the following error when trying a post request:

{
"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
}

[image]

Comment: I think you should submit it as JSON payload(`Json` Tab)

Comment: You should try pass the requisition with a JSON like Abdul said. 
And Change the variable **type** to another name.
type in Python is a built in function
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#type-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Abdul and Carlos mentioned, it needs to be submitted as a JSON payload